# Custom Center Tabs

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I'm trying to create a new custom center and center tab based on a standard one.
Is that possible?
I'm kind of stucked with the Classic Center Tab and the Employee Center tab.

Comment: what exactly are you asking ? is this related to oracle ?

Comment: Yes. It is related to Oracle NetSuite ERP.

Comment: Removing Oracle tag, the tag description: "a Multi-Model Database Management System created by Oracle Corporation. Do NOT use this tag for other products owned by Oracle".  NetSuite ERP falls into that other products category.